# no implementation found for 'torch.nn.functional.smooth_l1_loss'

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, fast-ai

I am trying to use the fastai library to build a machine learning model for object detection. I'm not an expert in machine learning, so I searched online and found this tutorial at [object detection tutorial](https://github.com/muellerzr/Practical-Deep-Learning-for-Coders-2.0/blob/master/Computer%20Vision/06_Hybridizing_Models.ipynb)
but when I used Google colab to run it, I got error saying:
TypeError: no implementation found for 'torch.nn.functional.smooth_l1_loss' on types that implement **torch_function**: [<class 'fastai.torch_core.TensorImage'>, <class 'fastai.vision.core.TensorBBox'>]
And I've also tried a 2018 version of the same tutorial before but ran into the same problem. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with environment setup. What steps did you follow to install fastai and other required packages, and what version of packages are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository you referred to in your question is outdated a/c to their README [here](https://github.com/muellerzr/Practical-Deep-Learning-for-Coders-2.0/blob/master/README.md).

You can find instructions to go to the latest versions of notebooks there.